# Group states and count number of zip codes in each state

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with ZIP codes and country state. For example:

```
zip state d1 d2
99501 AK 0.00 0.00 
99502 AK 0.00 0.00
99503 AK 0.00 0.00
36513 AL 0.04 0.04
36518 AL 0.04 0.04
```

I'm trying to group states and count number of ZIP in each state:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
  `#taxes`
GROUP BY
   `state`
```

How can I do this?

Comment: take a look at the answer below, then mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
    state, count(distinct zip)
FROM 
  `#taxes`
GROUP BY
   state
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT t.state, COUNT(*)
FROM `#taxes` t
GROUP BY t.state;
```

If a zip code could appear more than once for a given state, then you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT zip)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.